# Scatter Plot on C# do not render as expected X Axis

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I have created a scatter plot using point chart on C# with `datatable` as DataSource.

My `datatable` contain `double` data type. I tried to create scatter plot via `XValueMember-YValueMembers` and `DataBindingXY`, but the X-Axis, is not ordered by X Value, but by its index with X Value Label.

I have tried do some search at google, but found nothing.

**UPDATE**

I see that in my last row in my `DataTable` is empty (see on picture). Is that source of problem? just guessing.

[image: DataTable of dt at DataGridView]

Here is the graph look like. The X-Axis is ordered based on its index. (I Converted the data to single for capturing this image, since double has long number there, but the result is the same)
[image]

```
        public void dataGrid()
    {
    //Create data view to copy data from DataTable dt
        view = new DataView(dt);
        ids = view.ToTable("dt1", false, "DateTime", "MEAS", "SPT", "ACT");

        evaluationTable = new DataTable("evaluationTable");
        DataRow row;

   //Create a Column (internal function)
        evaluationTable.Columns.Add(AddDataColumn("DateTime"));
        evaluationTable.Columns.Add(AddDataColumn("ERROR"));
        evaluationTable.Columns.Add(AddDataColumn("ZERO"));
        evaluationTable.Columns.Add(AddDataColumn("MEAS"));
        evaluationTable.Columns.Add(AddDataColumn("OUT"));

    //Put data from DataView to DataTable and convert to Double
    //Raw Data, dt, was Numeric in StringType, and converted to double using this function
        foreach (DataRow _dt in ids.Rows)
        {
            row = evaluationTable.NewRow();
            row["DateTime"] = _dt["DateTime"];
            row["ERROR"] = ((Convert.ToDouble(_dt["MEAS"]) - Convert.ToDouble(_dt["SPT"]))/ Convert.ToDouble(_dt["SPT"])*100);
            row["ZERO"] = 0;
            row["MEAS"] = Convert.ToDouble(_dt["MEAS"]);
            row["OUT"] = Convert.ToDouble(_dt["ACT"]);
            evaluationTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }


    //DataGridView is working well, chartTrend3 was shown properly
    //chartTrend3 was not show a proper result
    //chartTrend3 is configured with Point Chart
        dataGridView2.DataSource = evaluationTable;
        chartTrend3.DataSource = evaluationTable;
    chartTrend3.Series["MEAS vs. OUT"].XValueMember = "MEAS"
        chartTrend3.Series["MEAS vs. OUT"].YValueMembers = "OUT"    

    }
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED**
I created a AddDataColumn function that turned all the DataColumn to String Type. So even when the value converted, the DataColumn still declared as String.

THANKS ANW (from Newbie of C#)

Comment: How about adding your code here?

Comment: We need to see exactly how the x-values are set, namely as numbers or as strings!!

Comment: updated the code and a picture of DataGridView from dt DataSource

Comment: The last row is just the default row to edit inserts. Not in the table. Turn off AllowUserToAddRows to avoid it. - What does the chart look like?

Comment: Hello @TaW, I have updated it with the chart capture

Comment: Hm. charttype Point can put points freely and should not reorder the data or the labels. Did you perhaps set Series.IsXValueIndexed ? (Btw, you may want to set a Format für the labels to restrict the digits!)

Comment: I Am So Sorry, i got where was the problem, my AddDataColumn function was convert the DataColumn to "String". Even i was converted to Single, the DataColumn was declared as String at all